# Is it possible to make a VBScript which executes a batch script within itself?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file, vbscript

I know it sounds strange, but my idea is creating a single text file which contains a VBScript and a Batch Script within it, i.e. if I run that script as a VBScript, it calls itself as a Batch script, and that batch script do some cmd.exe tasks.

I know you can use the .ShellExecute method and then run multiple commads using CMD /C [...], but this is a little difficult to read.

My try was:

```
If False Then
  goto batchLines
End If
[...VBScript continues here...]
Wscript.Quit
:batchLines
[...batch Script starts here...]
```

But as spected, it does not worked at all.

Comment: if there was then it might be more tricky than how shell execute with cmd /c looks   Maybe it's possible to put strings across multiple lines, and then do shell execute `cmd /c str` or  build up some string str that'd make up a batch script, write it to a temp bat file, then do shell execute cmd /c batchscript.  It's not what you ask for exactly, but it's just another way of getting the batch and the vbscript

Comment: It can easily be done in reverse. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/9074476/1012053 - in particular, pay attention to the WSF solution. Perhaps you can turn that on its head to have the VBS call itself as a batch script, but the script must have a .BAT (or .CMD) extension if you want it to run as batch. This means you must invoke the VBS using CSCRIPT with the `//E:VBS` option.

Comment: Here is a hybrid jscript/batch written by dbenham/dave benham.  jrepl.bat http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The opposite is possible (making a batch which runs VB script) [this](https://gist.github.com/krowe/9c2627dd5609832617c0) is an example.

```
@set @junk=1 /*
@echo off
REM Add Batch Stuff Here
if "%1" == "MOARBATCH" goto :MOARBATCH
cscript //nologo //E:jscript %~f0 %*
goto :eof */
// Add VBS stuff here
Wscript.Quit
/*
:MOARBATCH
REM More Batch Stuff Here
REM */
```

You can [go nuts](https://superuser.com/a/902081/145045) with this but AFAIK you need to begin with a batch file in order to take advantage of the Batch file handling quirks which this uses. BTW, this is often called a hybrid batch file.

Comment: thank you. I wanted to make a script like this, because I needed to run a batch requesting higher privileges (run as administrator). So, could the vbScript request higher privileges, then run "console commands" (without opening a new console window)?

Comment: By the way, I noticed that you use Jscript and also a feature of this language (multiline comment), so it seems this script should be written in javascript only.

Comment: VBScript hybrid batch files are possible but they are even more hackish. If at all possible I'd go with JScript. You may prefer to use an all Batch solution. I was going to write one for you when I found one already made: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28467343/932549

Comment: Since it is calling the JScript engine, does this even work with VBScript?